# table cell not appear in table view objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard

I have one tableviewcontroller class that connected to navigation controller.

but I don't know why when I run it my cell didn't appear, and I have just a navigation bar with a tab bar here is my code :

another problem is I want to have justify buttons in navigation bar in top but all my buttons are in the right I know that I used rightBarButtonItems but I don't know what should I right there for justify it .

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttons;
```

would you please helping me!
Thanks in advance!

![enter image description here][2]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

 UIBarButtonItem *menuButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menu" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone        target:self action:@selector(menu:)];
UIBarButtonItem *yearButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Year" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(year:)];
UIBarButtonItem *weekButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Week" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(week:)];
UIBarButtonItem *reportButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Report" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(report:)];

NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:menuButton,yearButton,weekButton,reportButton,nil];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttons;


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{

}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
//#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of sections.
return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//#warning Incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return 0;
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// Configure the cell...

 return cell;
 }
```

Comment: you have to return at least 1 section and a row in table

Comment: @CocoaMatters thanks for reply but I add 2 for both return but it's terminated and when i use 2 for first one it just shows the check in text would you please help me? and if it's possible write the code in answer section

Comment: Is the tableview's content defined as 'static' in your storyboard? If this is the case then just drop both methods (number of sections / rows) and you should be fine.

Comment: @Alladinian yes it's static it fine when I used return 4 for number of sections but it's crash when I wrote something in return for this methor   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

You have a static table view configured in the storyboard. Since you are not populating it with some kind of dynamic data you should be fine if you **delete** the hole code part **below**:

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source
```

Answer (score 0):

Has you set tableview's datasource and delegate from the .xib file? Also add some text in the delegate cellForRowAtIndexPath and check again.

Comment: no I used story board would you please help more I'm new to the iOS